# Where to publish short notes?

Tags: publishing

Where to publish short notes which don't deserve real publication (an article in a peer reviewed journal)?

I'd press it in blogs but even in blogs supporting math formulas ([wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com)) it is not very convenient to edit texts with formulas.

As an option: Put a PDF file online and post just a reference to it in a blog.

Better options?

Comment: Perhaps you should reconsider and do it on wordpress (or another blogging source) anyway? I have a math wordpress blog and it's not so bad, if you know some latex. Do you know $\LaTeX$?

Comment: @mixedmath: I know LaTeX. I used to be a LaTeX expert a few years before, now I remember not all but enough. Nevertheless I use TeXmacs not LaTeX to edit my manuscripts. I convert to LaTeX only before sending to a journal.

Comment: conceivably, I could help you with some of the formatting, or direct you to someone that can. If you're interested, you can go [here](http://mixedmath.wordpress.com/about/) (a wordpress account) to send me one such note or something.

Comment: It seems that some people put such things simply on their websites: [Pete L. Clark's Exposition's](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/expositions.html), [Expository papers by K. Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/).

Comment: Uploading it to arxiv (independently of publishing) might be also a good idea, just for the convenience of the readers.

Comment: Related at academia.se: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17094/

Answer (score 6):

If it is interesting for general audience, Amer. Math. Monthly would be a choice;
If it is also elementary, you may consider Elemente der Mathematik;
If you are patient enough, you may try Mathematical Notes (Russia).

Comment: "Elemente der Mathematik" seems being in German only. I studied German in a school but now don't remember at all this language. Thus it seems impossible for me to publish in Elemente der Mathematik. "Mathematical Notes" are in Russian, I know Russian as my native language. And yes, the note I am writing is very elementary, as the most nontrivial term I use in this note is "bijection". (If it weren't I would sent it to a specialized journal.)

Comment: It looks for me that Mathematical Notes would not publish this my note as being too elementary. The last choice of what you have offered is Amer. Math. Monthly. I'm considering to contact them.

Comment: Elemente der Mathematik also publish articles written in English for sure.

Comment: But I don't know how to prepare and send them an article as their site is in German only

Comment: @porton: http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/journal.php?jrn=em and http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/authorinfo.php?jrn=em

Comment: Are you Russian? I once tried to publish a paper at Doklady math, yet it seemed that the journal did not accept papers outside Russia. They did not even reply any message I sent.

Comment: Amer. Math. Monthly is not for original research.  They do have a Notes section for short snippets, though.

Comment: Amer. Math. Monthly is very difficult to get an article into.

Comment: @ Jim: It is much easier compared to American J. Math.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is exactly in the frame of your question, but Mathematica could be useful.

You could edit the notes in a Mathematica notebook (a very easy task), and then save them to HTML. By default the mathematics are saved as .gif images, but it does have the option to export to X/HTML+MathML. I think gifs are fine, though.

Here's a screen shot I took. On the left is a Mathematica notebook that I just wrote up. On the right is the output HTML version in a web browser.

[image: HTML export]

As you can see, the reproduction is very faithful.

Here's a picture of Mathematica's "writing assistant" to give you an idea of the sorts of formatting you can do:

[image]

And of course, you can always just highlight a piece of a Mathematica notebook, right click, and Copy As LaTeX. Example using the Ramanujan identity:

$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{1+x^2/(b+1)^2}{1+x^2/(a)^2}\times \frac{1+x^2/(b+2)^2}{1+x^2/(a+1)^2}\times \cdots dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\times \frac{\Gamma \left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma (b+1)\Gamma \left(b-a+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (a)\Gamma \left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma (b-a+1)}$

Comment: Addendum: Mathematica also exports to PDF and LaTeX, and you can export images into half a zillion formats. You can also Rasterize (convert to image) arbitrary expressions/graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Connexions [http://cnx.org/](http://cnx.org) seems to be something that fits your description. It allows you to upload pdfs etc and I think is exactly for the purpose of sharing such (educational) material.

The mathematica approach seems nice if you want to build a personal website but I'd advise you to put them in a pdf/ps and upload them to some document uploading site even if it is something like google docs. I mentioned Connexions above and there are plenty of such sites around. Just make sure you tag it well and provide a good description so that people can find it.

Also if you are writting in Latex, there are latex to HTML converters